# What is $\log(0/x)$?

Tags: logarithms

> $\log(a/b) = \log(a) - \log(b)$;
>   Is $\log(0/x) = -\log(x)$?

I watched a video claiming $\log(1/x) = -\log(x)$, which I get because $1/x = x^{-1}$ and $\log(x^y) = y(\log(x))$ but $\log(1)$... I get it, $\log(1) = 0$.

Back to my question $\log(0/x)$?

Comment: It is undefined.

Comment: ... beacause $0/x=0$ (if at least $x\ne 0$)

Comment: isnt 0/x undefined?

Comment: @James No. The symbol $\dfrac0 x$ can be defined as the only real number $r$ such that $rx=0$. What number with $r$ be?

Comment: i know x/infinity = 0 therefore x/0 = infinity therefore 0/x = 1/ infinity = r ???

Comment: What power of a positive real number equals zero?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\log\left(\frac{0}{x}\right) = \log 0$ is undefined, because $\log 0$ is itself undefined, because for any base $b\ne0$, there is no number $y$ such that $b^y=0$. (and you can't generally use $0$ as a base for the logarithm)

$\log\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = -\log x$, because $\log 1=0$.

Answer (score 2):

No, $\log\frac0x$ is not $-\log x$.
$$\log\frac0x=\log0-\log x$$
But remember, $\log0$ doesn't exist. At least not as real solution. EDIT: Well, $\log0$ is not imaginary solution either.

The other one with $\log\frac1x$ is correct though. There are actually more than one proof for it:
$$\log\frac1x=\log x^{-1}=-1\log x=-\log x$$
$$\log\frac1x=\log1-\log x=0-\log x=-\log x$$